# Socket.io 404es on Heroku on every port I tried

Tags: heroku, socket.io

I have the app running and it doesn't find socket.io and gives me 404.

this is the client:

```
<script src="http://game-test-1.herokuapp.com/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
<script>var socket = io.connect('http://game-test-1.herokuapp.com');</script>
```

and this is the server:

```
 var express = require('express'),
    routes = require('./routes'),
    user = require('./routes/user'),
    http = require('http'),
    path = require('path'),
    express = require("express"),
    app = express(),
    server = http.createServer(app),
    io = require('socket.io').listen(server);

server.listen(80);
```

I tried changing the ports and doing `http://game-test-1.herokuapp.com:81/...` but that gave me an error

How do I link socket.io correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Heroku requires that your application listens on a port of Heroku's choosing. Heroku will tell your application this port when it launches your application, via the `PORT` environment variable. If you listen on any other port, Heroku will ignore it and will terminate your application after 60 seconds.

Your users' browsers will still use ports 80 for HTTP traffic and 443 for HTTPS traffic. Heroku's routing layer, which is in-between the user's browser and your application, will send the HTTP traffic through to your application at the port Heroku designated for your application.

Answer (score 0):

Heroku Dev Center has a [guide on using socket.io on Heroku](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/using-socket-io-with-node-js-on-heroku). In particular, you'll need this bit of config:

```
// assuming io is the Socket.IO server object
io.configure(function () { 
  io.set("transports", ["xhr-polling"]); 
  io.set("polling duration", 10); 
});
```

Answer (score -1):

This is because Heroku does not support Websockets at this time (to the best of my knowledge) In order to use socket.io you need to force it to fallback to an xhr long-polling approach.